# Most important email headers to store separately in database

Tags: mysql, database, email, imap

I'm setting up an application to pull my emails and store them in a database.  At least at the moment, I'm not planning on using this application for actual email functionality.  Primarily I want to play around with different interfaces and feel much more comfortable using a DB-backend rather than IMAP.  (novice when it comes to email).

That being said, when designing my MySQL table for the messages, what would be the key headers to include in separate fields?  I think generally the reasons for parsing out separate headers would be:

- Speed of searching
- Categorization, i.e., by sender
- Reduction of storage, i.e., remembering duplicate emails or threads and just discarding them

Here are the headers I would like to grab, with my reasoning:

- To -- self-explanatory
- From -- self-explanatory
- Delivered to -- to catch when target is actually cc'd
- X-Mailer -- would be interesting to see what clients people are using
- Date -- categorize by date / time
- Subject -- self-explanatory
- Content-type -- choose how to display
- Message_ID -- for tracking duplicates (in case of pulling messages from OAuth, for example)

Given that the email standard, as I understand it, is pretty forgiving, and some (many?) emails will not even have some of these headers, I would appreciate your advice on what headers deserve their own field?  Or does every possible header need some love?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider having a separate "headers" table instead, with a 1:n relationship between E-Mails and headers.

```
id
mail_id           (ID of the E-Mail record this belongs to)
header_name       (Name of the header, e.g. "Content-type") 
header_content    (Content of the header)
position          (Optionally: The position this header is in in the E-Mail)
```

It would be better design and allow you to store an unlimited number of headers.

Answer (score 2):

> To -- self-explanatory

Self-explanatory? I think not. It's not necessarily the recipient of the email (which is deterined by the SMTP envelope) so bearing that in mind, why are you excluding the 'cc' header / the bcc envelope addressee? While 'delivered to' might indicate some of the information there's a lot of ambiguity here.

What data you store depends on what data you need and how you intend processing it - and you've not given a very good explanation of either.

Would it be that much of an overhead to store all the headers? Especially if you store the header definition as data (rather than a column name) e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE email (
   id INT not null auto-increment,
   body LONGTEXT
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE header (
   id INT not null auto-increment, 
   /* some headers can occur multiple times, e.g. received from */
   email_id INT,
   header VARCHAR(30),
   value VARCHAR(40)
   PRIMARY KEY (id), INDEX email(email_id, header), INDEX liame(header, email_id)
);
```

This gives you the flexibility to apply a black list rather than just a whitelist (i.e. pick the headers you don't want to record).